# Как удалить перенос строки между определенными элементами

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо поднять комментарий на строку элемента выше, используя средства PHP. Делать это нужно только если элемент выше называется "set". Как я понял из прочитанного в интернете, необходимо использовать регулярные выражения, но я в них теряюсь.

Как это выглядит сейчас:

```
<set name="xxx" value="xxx"/>
<!-- Комментарий -->
```

Как должно:

```
<set name="xxx" value="xxx"/> <!-- Комментарий -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Нашел решение:

```
preg_replace('#(\<set[^\>]*>)\r\n(\<!--[^\>]*>)#is', '\\1 \\2', $output_file);
```

Comment: Не совсем верное решение, нужно учитывать не только перенос строки а еще и табуляцию, она везде разная, т.е в условии (\r\n) не верно. Как добавить в условие неопределенное количество табуляций (\t) после (\r\n)?

Comment: Нашел решение, спасибо всем: (\r\n\t{1,10})